# Where do you find the Rust docs for collect() after you split a string?

Tags: string, rust

Where can I find the docs on `.collect()`?

```
fn main() {
    let split = "some string 123 ffd".split("123");
    let vec: Vec<&str> = split.collect();
    println!("{:#?}",vec);
}
```

Comment: I recomend you to read [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) as well as using a search engine of your trust, e.g. duckduckgo https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rust+collect+doc .

Comment: The rust docs include a search engine: [collect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/index.html?search=collect)

Comment: Can also search the documentation of the Rust standard library directly from DuckDuckGo: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!rust+collect

Comment: @cyclaminist amazing! My mind is blown away today 

Comment: @cyclaminist Wow, this will safe me some time in the future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect

[`split()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) returns an iterator, so you're looking for the [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) function of the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait.

Comment: To be more precise - [split](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) returns [Split](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html) structure. `Split` implements [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html#impl-Iterator) trait. `Iterator` trait has [collect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) method.